# Can we exclude a custom service provider when running php artisan migrate in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, service-provider, artisan-migrate

I have a custom service provider in which I am accessing a model in `boot()`. But when I run `php artisan migrate`, it shows the below error:

`[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '********' doesn't exist`

I found that if we add `if (!app()->runningInConsole()) {` inside `boot()`, it works successfully.

This is the code we have used in the service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->bindCurrentPartToNav();
}
```

```
private function bindCurrentPartToNav(): void
{
    $currentPartName = \App\Http\Helpers\Part::getPartName();

    view()->composer(
        'includes.partials.part',
        function ($view) use ($currentPartName) {
            $view->with('currentPartName', $currentPartName);
        }
    );
}
```

Helper file:

```
public static function getPartName(): ?string
{
    return PartModel::PartKey()->active()->pluck('name')->first();
}
```

Model:

```
public function scopePartKey($query): Builder
{
    return $query->where('identifier', config('env.PART_KEY'));
}
```

Is there any way to remove that service provider from `php artisan migrate` so that we can remove `runningInConsole()` check in each refresh?

Thanks for your help in advance.
[image]

Comment: if your code depend on the session level, the it should not be in your model level. keep the C out of your M in your MVC application. (yeah broad question leads to broad answer)

Comment: @N69S It doesn't depend on the session. I want to get a name from the table based on the env value in the service provider.

Comment: well if the name depends on if the call is coming from frontend or CLI, then it depends on the session. Share some code of the boot() method you're talking about and we might help you.

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the code there, it's unreadable in the comment section

Comment: So, in your Model boot() method there is a call that to a view composition (which might also have some session dependency). Keep your V out of your M in your MVC. I still dont see why this trigger an error about migration... Your question needs more debug & details.

Comment: I have updated the question with code in helper and model. 
When we set up the project, the migration will not run because it throws an error because of the missing table.

Comment: It will work with(\Schema::hasTable('table')) check. But this is not a good solution, I think. Any help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 2):

As any environment configuration, in your case a general configuration, you should assign a default value fall back.

```
public static function getSectionName(): ?string
{
    try {
        return SectionModel::sectionKey()->active()->value('name');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This will simulate the case where the section model with that specific `identification_key` is missing in the database.

This will also prevent any issues with the initial migration.

But in the end, you tied a model with a view rendering code. You should find another solution to dissociate them. For example, you can move the boot() code out of the model and link it to a middleware.

You can also use Singleton pattern (since it's like a general unique config across the application)